# Azure / Github deploy doesnt work anymore

Tags: azure, github, deployment

In the past I would deploy Spring boot apps via Azure using the Github integration. So when adding the web app to azure I indicate that I want to deploy a Github project. That worked perfectly in the past.

Now, 21st march 2024, I want to do the exact same thing. So I create an webapp in Azure with the name **backend** and I deploy the new web app using Azure by indicating I want to deploy a github project. I can see that in github oin my project that a .github/workflows folder is made with a workflow file in it. In the Actions tab of github I can see that the workflow file has started an action however the deploy fails because I get an error that the resource **backend** doesn't exist! This used to work. Is there a known bug in Azure that deployment through github doesnt work anymore?

Comment: If possible can you share your repo?

Comment: Can you once share your GitHub Actions workflow logs

Comment: I have the github action log. How can I share it with you? I have a text file with the log in it.

Comment: Could you please add it in the question?

Comment: @Martijn Hiemstra In your Github Repository you can find .github/workflow file like [this](https://i.imgur.com/uKHBo96.png) and copy the workflow past it here.

Comment: @Martijn Hiemstra Your Resource name in Azure is backend. Am I Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the workflow file created in your GitHub repository's `.github/workflows` directory. Ensure that it
Examine the workflow file in your GitHub repository's `.github/workflows` directory. Make sure it specifies the correct Azure Web App name ("backend") and includes the appropriate configurations. Look for any errors or misconfigurations within the workflow file.

I developed a simple Hello world Java Spring Boot application and successfully deployed it to Azure App Service using GitHub.

**Local Output**:

[image]

For deployment purposes, I ran the following command:

`mvn clean install`

I created a web app in Azure, as shown below.

[image]

After filling the necessary details, click the "Review+Create" option.

[image]

After creating the web app, go to the Deployment Center, select GitHub as the Source, and fill in the necessary details as shown below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Below is my GitHub workflow configuration.

**.github/workflow Configuration**:

```yaml
name: Build and deploy JAR app to Azure Web App - <AzureWebAppName>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Java version
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '17'

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn clean install

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: java-app
          path: '${{ github.workspace }}/target/*.jar'

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
      
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: java-app
      
      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: '<AzureWebAppName>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: '*.jar'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_<key> }}
```

I successfully deployed the Spring Boot application to Azure App Service, as shown below.

[image]

**Azure App Service Output**:

[image]